# what's with all these invisible classes  in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, class, mobile

I am trying to customize jQuery mobile CSS to fit more form elements on a page. By poking around with Firebug I can see hidden classes that seem to be added at run time based on data-roles.  Is this an HTML5 or a jQueryMobile technique (or both combined) Is this documented anywhere or do I have to discover by trial and error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a jQuery Mobile thing.  The idea is that you're defining structure, not styling, and jQuery Mobile is translating your structure into CSS styling at runtime. If you can avoid changing the CSS directly (and sometimes you can't), things will go more smoothly.

Have you tried using [jQuery Mobile's grid layout features](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/content/content-grids.html) to position your form elements?  That might work better.

Comment: "jQuery Mobile's grid layout features" It looks like a good start but somewhat limited.  It might be nice have controls that allow you to shrink padding around, and height of  form components.

Comment: I think you might be able to use an inset list inside the grid to accomplish that without custom styling, or maybe a regular list if you wanted to push it to the edges (not sure if that does happen inside the grid layout containers though).